# How to refresh XML Schema in OxygenXML

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd, oxygenxml

I'm developing a new DTD schema in OxygenXML, and using a sample XML document to verify it meets our requirements.

When I change the DTD it's understandable that the document can become invalid.  But when I fix the document, it remains invalid because OxygenXML appears to be cacheing the DTD.  Closing and re-opening the document doesn't update the schema.

Only closing and re-opening OxygenXML refreshes the app's version of the schema.

Is there a hidden command to clear cached schemas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the tab of the opened XML document selected, just use the "Validate" button from the toolbar, pressing it should reset any cache Oxygen has about the schema used in the XML doc for validation or content completion.

Comment: Couldn't have hoped for a more authoritative answer, thanks Radu!